# gdal library integration error for android

Tags: android, gdal

I am working on application which required to read and write shapefile for that i am using gdal library. I have followed all steps mentioned at library page [`GDAL4Android`](https://github.com/paamand/GDAL4Android) and I have also made changes in gradle file as but still i am getting error org or library classes or not accessible in main activity.

### setting.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Gdal"
include ':app'
include ':app', ':GDAL'
```

### build.gradle app level dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.6.0'
    implementation project(':GDAL')
}
```